# Plugins folder has not been created on Ionic 4 Capacitor app

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, capacitor

I have deleted `node_modules` and `plugins` folder `package-lock.json` and after that, I have run `npm i`

But it doesn't install a `plugins` folder. So what command should I use for creating plugins folder? This is the `Ionic 4 Capacitor` app.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "mobiger",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "PropelApps",
  "homepage": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.4.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "1.4.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^1.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.20",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.0.2 (C:\Users\Sampath\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.5.0
   @capacitor/core : 1.4.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.9.0) : 0.8.1
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0)  : 0.2.5

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Sampath\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.12.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plugins` folder is a Cordova folder, not a Capacitor folder

Capacitor plugins are read directly from node_modules, they are not copied anywhere.

Cordova plugins get copied to `ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins` and to `android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins`.

Those folders get created/updated on `npx cap update` command